# Why am I seeing undesirable rendering results using VBOs like this?

Tags: opengl, rendering, vbo

I am trying to write a program that renders using VBO(vertex buffer objects). Everything works great except that when I run the program, It looks like the object is spazzing out. I think its due to the fact that I am trying to delete the buffers, but I could not fix the problem no matter what I have done. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong with the piece of code?
Appreciate it.

```
    GLuint VBOvertex;
    GLuint VBOTexCoord;
    GLuint VBONormal;

//////////////////////////VERTEX BUFFER
glGenBuffers(1, &VBOvertex);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBOvertex);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(m->verticies)*3,m->verticies,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

///////////////////////////TextCoord BUFFER
glGenBuffers(1, &VBOTexCoord);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBOTexCoord);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(m->TextCoord)*2,m->TextCoord,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//////////////////////////////NORMAL BUFFER
glGenBuffers(1, &VBONormal);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBONormal);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(m->Normal)*3,m->Normal,GL_STATIC_DRAW);


delete[]m->verticies; 
m->verticies=NULL;
delete[]m->TextCoord;
m->TextCoord=NULL;
delete[]m->Normal;
m->Normal=NULL;


glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBOvertex);
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOTexCoord);
glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,0,0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBONormal);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0,0);


glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,m->nbrTris*3);


glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

Comment: by looking quickly at your code I can tell you are not copying the index buffer, and using glDrawElements.. you should use glDrawArrays (as I recall ) if you don't have index buffer.

Comment: @concept3d thanks for the answer. When you say index buffer are you talking about the glBufferSubData?

Comment: No, glBufferSubData is for updating an exsisting buffer. There are two ways to draw a buffer. Using indices, or directly from the vertex array, what are you doing is mixing the two methods. check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_mesh it differentiates between the two ways.

Comment: @concept3d  ok, so instead of glDrawElements, I am using `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,m->numberoffaces*3);` I kind of understand what you mean, but I don't know how I can implement it.

Comment: check this http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html

Comment: @concept3d I actually used that and NeHe's Tutorials to build what I have :)

Comment: but you are still misusing the functions, you need to revise your code.

Comment: actually the tutorial is implementing index arrays, and you are using vertex arrays

Comment: @concept3d I was trying to use vertex arrays thought It would be easier, because the code I found that I a using to render VBO is easier to work with vertex arrays.

Comment: ok then you need to use glDrawArrays instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're using VBONormal to supply data to all 3 gl*Pointer calls, you need to call the APIs in the correct order.
2. You are giving a pointer into CPU memory, but when a VBO is enabled, the pointer needs to be relative to the VBO.
3. What concept3d said about your indices is correct also, I'll leave it to you to fix that (but it *should* work the way you have it, just very slowly)

It should look more like:

```
...
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

//Bind
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBOvertex);
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOTexCoord);
glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,0,0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBONormal);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0,0);
...
```

I think you didn't read the manual carefully ;)

---

EDIT: Looking over your code again I see another issue: glBufferData needs to know the **total** size in bytes, not the size per vertex, since it needs to copy all the data when you call it.

Should look something like this:

```
...
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    m->nbrVertices*sizeof(float)*3,
    m->verticies,
    GL_STATIC_DRAW);
...
```

Comment: hey man thanks for the answer, I changed some stuff on my code and edited my question. If you could take a look that would be great

Comment: done and edited my answer accordingly, I've analysed every line now, if you still have an issue after trying my 2nd reccomendation, you'll need to package up your code in a format where I can try to run it myself.

Comment: if you can email me at kimjohnson89@hotmail.com. I can send you my source code.Thanks